# jQuery compability issue and undefined result in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, explorer, attr

I wrote a jQuery script that works correctly in Opera and Firefox, but Internet Explorer has a problem.

When I start testing the script its return correct text with  `alert ( prlvg.attr('prl') );` in Opera and Firefox, but in Explorer it returns `undefined`

The previous steps where I get `prlvg` is there:

```
var top = $('a[prl]:first').offset().top; 
var vwtmbs = $('a[prl]').filter(function(){
    var offsetW = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    return(offsetW <= window.innerHeight );
});

prlvg = vwtmbs.last();
alert ( prlvg.attr('prl') );
```

How to fix the problem? thanks.

**UPDATED:** seems problem at `window.innerHeight` its is `undefined` at IE and all code after that is also undefined.

Comment: alert ( prlvg.attr('prl') ); after all code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer, 7 through 10, is handling your custom attribute just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/xpjcU/.

Aside from that, I would steer away from using custom attributes like this in your HTML. Instead, use the [`data-` attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) if you want to store extra information about your elements:

```
<p data-prl="foo">Bar</p>
```

You can then interact with thsi custom data via [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: there is no problem to witch tag to add `data-` ? If its will be <a data-prl> its will be ok? thanks

Comment: @abrahab No, there should be no problem with `data-prl`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Explorer version may not take your custom `attr`. I propose you to pass this in a class like : `class="prl_foo"` and select it with `$(a).hasClass(...)` or `$("a[class^='prl_']")`